# IOS: Can I periodically scan for dynamically changing BLE advertisement records in background?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here is my scenario ..

I have a device that advertises dynamic data per BLE protocol. There are multiple such devices operating for a user

Questions -

1) Can IOS scan such constantly changing advertising data or does it expect advertising packets to be pretty static?

2) Can we create a service that scans for such packets periodically - maybe 30s every 5 minutes?

3) Can such a service be automatically restarted during bootup without user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a service on a normal (non-jailbroken) phone. Isn't even possible to distribute something like that (read the [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)). Sure, you can scan for BLE data on whatever interval you want, but your app needs to be active, or it needs to be doing something approved by Apple for making connections to BLE devices in the background. Just be aware that like any other background app, iOS might suspend or terminate your app at any time, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is covered by the standard BLE background mode - it is covered in the Core Bluetooth programming guide.

You can set up a scan for specific service UUIDs and this will continue in the background. Your app will be launched into the background when a device is discovered.

The exact scheduling of the notification can't be controlled - but in my experience you are notified pretty much as soon as a new peripheral is discovered. Once you have discovered a device you can even initiate a connection as soon as it disconnects (ie goes out of range) - iOS will automatically reconnect to the device when it comes back into range

In order for the scan or pending connection to survive across reboots you must configure state restoration. This is also covered in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide.